# Bind pure virtual method

Tags: c++, pure-virtual, stdbind

Suppose we have the following hierarchy:

```
class Add3Interface {
  virtual int add3 (const int&) const = 0;
};

class Add3: public Add3Interface {
  virtual int add3 (const int& arg) const override {
    return arg + 3;
  }
};
```

I want to bind the `add3` method so I can use it in things like `std::views::transform`.
The following code is fine:

```
const Add3 myAdder{};
const auto myFun = std::bind(&Add3::add3, myAdder, std::placeholder::_1);
```

However, in my use case, I don't have access to the concrete type, so I have to write something like this:

```
auto foo(Add3Interface& myAdder) {
    const auto myFun = std::bind(&Add3Interface::add3, myAdder,
                                 std::placeholders::_1);
    // ...
}
```

However, this makes the compiler upset:

```
/usr/include/c++/11/tuple:238:13: error: cannot declare field ‘std::_Head_base<0, Add3Interface, false>::_M_head_impl’ to be of abstract type ‘Add3Interface’
```

How can I bind my object's method?

I hoped something like `typeid` might help:

```
const auto myFun = std::bind(&(typeid(myAdder)::add3), myAdder, std::placeholders::_1);
```

But that only led to various syntax errors, which differed depending on how I positioned the various parentheses.

Naturally we could just use a lambda:

```
const auto myFun = [&myAdder] (const auto& arg) { return myAdder.add3(arg); };
```

But I'd prefer to use `bind` if possible, as I feel it represents what I am trying to do better from a semantic point of view.

Comment: `, myAdder,` => `, std::ref(myAdder),`

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI that should be posted as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: Deriving from `Add3Interface` slipped when copying the various bits. I edited the question.

Comment: I think the lambda better represents what you are trying to do better from a semantic point of view.  (Now that we have lambdas, `std::bind` can go the way of the `std::auto_ptr`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::bind` attempts to store all of its arguments *by-value*. In this case, it is trying to copy `myAdder` into a data member of type `Add3Interface`. Of course, as `Add3Interface` is abstract, this fails. The issue is not with the member function pointer having the wrong type.

If you want `std::bind` to refer to a stored argument by reference, pass a `std::reference_wrapper<T>` instead of a `T`. You can use the convenience functions `std::ref` or `std::cref` to construct `std::reference_wrapper`s.

```cpp
auto foo(Add3Interface& myAdder) {
    const auto myFun = std::bind(&Add3Interface::add3, std::ref(myAdder),
                                 std::placeholders::_1);
    // ...
}
```

(To be precise, `std::bind` doesn't itself handle `std::reference_wrapper` specially at all. It will just store a copy of the `std::reference_wrapper` as a data member just like it stores a copy of any other argument. The `std::reference_wrapper` is correctly unwrapped at the time of the function call because the standard [`INVOKE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) operation that many standard utilities use to invoke callables unwraps it.)

Answer (score 0):

> However, in my use case, I don't have access to the concrete type, so I have to write something like this

In case if you want to pass any instance of the `Add3Interface`, you can define static member function which calls the member function:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Add3Interface {
  virtual int add3 (const int&) const = 0;
  static int staticAdd3 (Add3Interface const& ths, const int& arg) { return ths.add3(arg); }
};


struct Add3: Add3Interface {
  virtual int add3 (const int& arg) const override {
    return arg + 3;
  }
};

struct Add4: Add3Interface {
  virtual int add3 (const int& arg) const override {
    return arg + 4;
  }
};

int main()
{
   auto myFun = std::bind(Add3Interface::staticAdd3, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
   Add4 add4;
   Add3 add3;
   std::cout << myFun(add3, 1) << "\n";
   std::cout << myFun(add4, 1) << "\n";
}
```